# Error when working with i18n country code in Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: mobile, internationalization, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I have an app built with titanium (Alloy) with strings in pt-PT, pt-BR and en-US.
Currently, if I have a folder en and pt it works just fine, although if I add the country code the build process breaks. (*titanium build -p android -T device*)

I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to package application:
[ERROR]
[ERROR] invalid resource directory name:
[PATH TO MY APP]\build\android\res values-pt-PT
[PATH TO MY APP]\build\android\res values-pt-BR
[PATH TO MY APP]\build\android\res values-en-US
```

It looks a lot like a bug in alloy/titanium but I can't actually confirm that. Any ideas?

SDK Version: 3.5.1

Targets: iOS, Android (currently testing on android but will have to work on iOS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Project > Clean ... and select the project from the list. If that did not work add 'r' in front of region. That means, folder name should be "pt-rPT" instead of "pt-PT". My suspicion Android gets res folders starting with 'r'. Yes, odd work around but worked once.

BTW what Titanium SDK are you using?

Comment: Version 3.5.1. It works! Thanks a lot, that is really odd but ok. Now I have to find out if I can change the locale in runtime (I'm using the locale module https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/7210#!overview) and how to make that work in iOS as well. Any ideas?

Comment: Looking at the Titanium code you may be able to change Locale at runtime on iOS see [setLanguage](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/iphone/Classes/LocaleModule.m#L73) method. On Android it's a feature not implemented yet on the [LocaleModule](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/android/modules/locale/src/java/ti/modules/titanium/locale/LocaleModule.java#L89).

Comment: Changing the locale is possible with the module i'm using. The problem is making the country code work on iOS. Using pt-rPT doesn't seem to work for iOS =/

Comment: Ok, after some tests iOS works with plain pt-PT, but it needs to have a pt folder to work with pt-BR. IMO it is quite terrible but I think I can solve it with some sym links. Thanks for the help!!